# Python: Merge the string in the list (first element) based on the second element

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, nested-lists, named-entity-recognition, defaultdict

I have a nested list:

```
"Add changes & things to hot 50 playlist"
"add Madchild to Electro Latino"
"Add artist to my 80'S PARTY"

slot_list = [[['changes', 'entity_name'], ['&', 'entity_name'], ['things', 'entity_name'], ['hot', 'playlist'], ['50', 'playlist']], 
[['Madchild', 'artist'], ['Electro', 'playlist'], ['Latino', 'playlist']],
[['artist', 'music_item'], ['my', 'playlist_owner'], ["80'S", 'playlist'], ['PARTY', 'playlist']]]
```

I want to merge the string in the [0] position together when their [1] position (slot) elements are the same. And still keep the same nested structure, since that they belong to the same sentence.

the expected output:

```
output = [[['entity_name', 'changes & things'], ['playlist', 'hot 50']],
 [['artist', 'Madchild'], ['playlist', 'Electro Latino']], [['music_item', 'artist'], 
 ['playlist_owner', 'my'], ['playlist', "80's PARTY"]]]
```

This is the code I used:

```
dic = defaultdict(str)
for element in slot_list:
    for word, slot in element:
        dic[slot] += ' ' + str(word)
print([[word, slot] for word, slot in dic.items()])
```

and I got:

```
[['entity_name', ' changes & things'], ['playlist', " hot 50 Electro Latino 80'S PARTY"], ['artist', ' Madchild'], ['music_item', ' artist'], ['playlist_owner', ' my']]
```

, which combine the *words* with same *slot* together because of the key-value pair in dict.
I also tried **groupby** but it also does not work out.

Hope someone can give me some guidance! Thanks!

Comment: can you share the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some denomination:

- A pair is a list containing two string elements: the
  first one (value) is the value represented by the second
  one (key), so the `['changes', 'entity_name']` pair represents
  a entity name of value "changes", and the `['hot', 'playlist']`
  pair represents a playlist of value "hot".
- A slot is a list of pairs.

Assuming their [1] position are sorted and a slot is

```py
[
    ['changes', 'entity_name'],
    ['&', 'entity_name'],
    ['things', 'entity_name'],
    ['hot', 'playlist'],
    ['50', 'playlist'],
]
```

you can group the slot using each pair's second element

```py
# itertools.groupby(slot, key=lambda x: x[1])
[
    ['entity_name', [
        ['changes', 'entity_name'],
        ['&', 'entity_name'],
        ['things', 'entity_name'],
    ],
    ['playlist', [
        ['hot', 'playlist'],
        ['50', 'playlist']
    ],
]
```

For each grouped pairs, join all the first elements using a space:

```py
import itertools

def group_slots(slots):
    # For each slot in the list of slots, group it
    return [group_slot(slot) for slot in slots]

def group_slot(slot): 
    return [[key, ' '.join(pair[0] for pair in pairs)] 
            for key, pairs in itertools.groupby(slot, key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

Then

```
slots = [
    [
        ['changes', 'entity_name'],
        ['&', 'entity_name'],
        ['things', 'entity_name'],
        ['hot', 'playlist'],
        ['50', 'playlist'],
    ],
    [
        ['Madchild', 'artist'],
        ['Electro', 'playlist'],
        ['Latino', 'playlist'],
    ],
    [
        ['artist', 'music_item'],
        ['my', 'playlist_owner'],
        ["80'S", 'playlist'],
        ['PARTY', 'playlist'],
    ],
]
result = group_slots(slots)
print(result)
```

outputs

```
[
    [
        ['entity_name', 'changes & things'],
        ['playlist', 'hot 50'],
    ],
    [
        ['artist', 'Madchild'], 
        ['playlist', 'Electro Latino'],
    ],
    [
        ['music_item', 'artist'], 
        ['playlist_owner', 'my'], 
        ['playlist', "80'S PARTY"],
    ],
]
```

Comment: It's a smart way! Thank you so much for the idea!!

Answer (score 0):

From your output, it appears that you want to merge strings within each sentence. However, the loop you wrote shares the same dictionary across all of the sentences. Here's a code example that uses a new dictionary for each sentence:

```py
new_list = []
for element in slot_list:
    dic = defaultdict(str)
    for word, slot in element:
        dic[slot] += ' ' + str(word)
    new_list.append([[slot, word.lstrip()] for slot, word in dic.items()])

print(new_list)
```

(Also, notice the `slot.lstrip()` to get rid of the leading whitespace.)

Output:

```
[[['entity_name', 'changes & things'], ['playlist', 'hot 50']],
 [['artist', 'Madchild'], ['playlist', 'Electro Latino']], 
 [['music_item', 'artist'], ['playlist_owner', 'my'], ['playlist', "80'S PARTY"]]]
```

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much! it's really helpful!